# How to make a Windows shortcut to run a function in a Python script?

Tags: python, windows, windows-shortcut

I am trying to find a way to create a Windows shortcut that executes a function from a Python file.
The function being run would look something like this (it runs a command in the shell):

```
def function(command):
    subprocess.run(command, shell = True, check = True)
```

I am aware that you can run `cmd` functions and commands directly with a shortcut, but I would like it to be controlled by Python.

I have little experience working with Windows shorcuts, so the best I can do is show you the following:

[image: screenshot of shortcut properties dialog box]

This is what I imagine it would like like.

After a quick Google search, the only help I can find is how to make a shortcut with Python, not how to run a function from it. So hopefully what I am asking is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking AFAIK, you can't do it, however it could be done if the target script is written a certain way and is passed the name of the function to run as an argument. You could even add arguments to be passed to the function by listing them following its name in the shortcut.

The target script has to be set up with an `if __name__ == '__main__':` section similar to what is shown below which executes the named function it is passed as a command line argument. The `input()` call at the end is there just to make the console window stay open so what is printed can be seen.

`target_script.py`:

```
def func1():
    print('func1() running')

def func2():
    print('func2() running')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from pathlib import Path
    import sys

    print('In module', Path(__file__).name)

    funcname = sys.argv[1]
    vars()[funcname]()  # Call named function.

    input('\npress Enter key to continue...')
```

To make use of it you would need to create a shortcut with a `Target:` set to something like:

**`python D:\path_to_directory\target_script.py func1`**

Output:

```
In module target_script.py
func1() running

press Enter key to continue...
```

##### Generalizing

It would also be possible to write a script that could be applied to other scripts that **weren't** written like `target_script`.

`run_func_in_module.py`:

```
import importlib.util
from pathlib import Path
import sys

mod_filepath = Path(sys.argv[1])
funcname = sys.argv[2]

# Import the module.
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(mod_filepath.stem, mod_filepath)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

# Call the specified function in the module.
mod_func = getattr(module, funcname)
mod_func()
```

To make use of this version you would need to create a shortcut with a `Target:` set to something like:

**`python D:\path_to_directory\run_func_in_module.py D:\another_directory\target_script.py func2`**

Note that the `target_script.py` would no longer need the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section at the end (although having one would do no harm).